# Is it possible to replace a 1x1 wireless laptop card with a 2x2 card?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop

This is my first time asking a question on Stack Exchange, so if I've posted my question in the wrong forum or format, please let me know.

I'm trying to upgrade my laptop's wireless card. The card that I currently have says in the specs that it has a 1x1 antenna. I want to replace it with a much newer card with a 2x2 antenna. As far as I can tell, the connections on both cards look the same, so it seems like this ought to work. Is it possible to make this switch?

If so, is it something that I can do myself after watching some Youtube videos, or is it better to let a professional do it. (It doesn't look too hard to me, but I don't want to break something.)

Thank you so much in advance for your time and help!

**More specifics:**

**Old card:** Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165,
[Specs](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/89450/intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-3165.html),
[Website with pictures of a card with the same specs](https://www.newegg.com/p/12Z-0011-026T1?item=9SIAH719948742&source=region&nm_mc=knc-googlemkp-pc&cm_mmc=knc-googlemkp-pc-_-pla-compuparts+solutions-_-cd%2fdvd+r%2frw+media-_-9SIAH719948742&gclid=CjwKCAjwrKr8BRB_EiwA7eFappAOTqKtv6UkRhAs7KKMUKn4eWEy__zyF3mZRH7DRn8DjALq7o05KRoCI-gQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds#)

**New card:** Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200,
[Specs](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/189347/intel-wi-fi-6-ax200-gig.html),
[Website with pictures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SH6GV5S)

**Laptop model:** Dell Inspiron 7773

Comment: It should work fine, but you will definitely want to replace the 1x1 antenna with a 2x2, otherwise you will not see a speed increase. Even if you only replaced the antenna, you would see a speed increase. A 1x1 is not even capable of using N/AC to its full potential. The laptop companies are cheap. Something like: https://www.amazon.com/Bluetooth-IPEX-Internal-Antenna-M-2/dp/B07QDTXGGJ I think most people are capable of making this swap. It is pretty self explanatory once you open the laptop if you have replaced mobile hardware before.

Comment: @Narzard. I just looked it up, and it appears that to replace the antenna's, I have to take apart the screen, which appears to be glued together. I don't want to mess with that. If I just replace the card, will I at least get the Bluetooth 5 functionality? Or will I just have the Bluetooth 5 protocols and such, but without the increased physical range? 

Also, I bought the computer in 2018. Is there any chance that they built it with 2x2 antenna's and just used a 1x1 card?